# Mixpanel Android - consecutive timeEvent requests scenario

Tags: mixpanel

**Background**

I'm referring to this documentation about [timeEvent](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android#event_timing):

```
MixpanelAPI mixpanel =
    MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context, MIXPANEL_TOKEN);

// start the timer for the event "Image Upload"
mixpanel.timeEvent("Image Upload");

// stop the timer if the imageUpload() method returns true
if(imageUpload()){
    mixpanel.track("Image Upload");
}
```

The method description explains:

> Begin timing of an event. Calling timeEvent("Thing") will not send an
>   event, but when you eventually call track("Thing"), your tracked event
>   will be sent with a "$duration" property, representing the number of
>   seconds between your calls.

**Question**

It looks like `imageUpload()` will return a boolean. if it's `true` then Mixpanel will track this event with `duration` property specified..

However, it does not state what will happen if imageUpload() returns `false`.. What if I have two consecutive calls to this `uploadImage()` method and the first one returns `false` and the following returns `true`? will that mess up the event tracking?

the calling sequence will be:

```
// first upload
mixpanel.timeEvent("Image Upload");
// first upload failed

// second upload
mixpanel.timeEvent("Image Upload");
// second upload succeeded
mixpanel.track("Image Upload");
```

will the second `timeEvent` override the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the source code on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/blob/ca5c0d9e74217c6d5ce5e9afa58397c5d1346a14/src/main/java/com/mixpanel/android/mpmetrics/MixpanelAPI.java#L406)), it is clear that if the first upload doesn't call `track("Image Upload")`, then the second `timeEvent("Image Upload")` will override the first timing, and only the second event will be tracked.